# ObjectMapper explicitly printing carriage returns and escaping quotation marks in my JSON

Tags: json, regex, spring, groovy, jackson

Been asked to modify a project to save space in our console and log files that has the following Spring application property **which I've been asked to leave in place**:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

Obviously, that's going to pretty print all of our JSON and take up a ton of space in the console and log files.

The application has a groovy class that extends Spring's OncePerRequestFilter class that grabs HTTP requests and responses and sends them through a groovy class that masks sensitive data.  This class has a method that takes in a string which is essentially the stringified version of the request's or response's body.

Once the string has been masked, it is run through Jackson's ObjectMapper to basically undo the spring application property to make every print pretty:

**Code #1:**

```
return objectMapper.writer().without(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(stringToWrite);
```

Here's some example input that will be going through the code:

```
{
  "person" : {
    "personName" : "BAR,      FOO",
  }
}
```

... and the result ends up being ...

**Result #1:**

```
"{\r\n  \"person\" : {\r\n    \"personName\" : \"BAR,      FOO\",\r\n    }\r\n    }"
```

... trying to take the easy way out, I figured applying a simple .replaceAll() on the string would knock out the explicit quote escapes and carriage returns, but I found the carriage returns disappeared and that the quote escapes just come right back...

**Code #2:**

```
return objectMapper.writer().without(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(stringToWrite.replaceAll("\\\"", '"').replaceAll("\\r", "").replaceAll("\\n", ""));
```

**Result #2:**

```
"{  \"person\" : {    \"personName\" : \"BAR,      FOO\"  }  }"
```

... and finally, if I just use

**Code #3**

```
.replaceAll("\\\"", "")
```

... instead of what I used in Code #2 which was ...

```
.replaceAll("\\\"", '"')
```

... then I get ...

**Result #3**

```
"{  person : {    personName : BAR,      FOO  }  }"
```

... but what is asked of me is ...

**Desired Result:**

```
"{  "person" : {    "personName" : "BAR,      FOO"  }  }"
```

It appears to be a result of something the objectMapper is using, but I'm a little at a loss at this point.

Comment: What happens when you print it out? `println result`

Comment: @tim_yates - if i println just the stringToWrite using the .replaceAll("\\\"", ""), then my desired result is printed to the console.  This circumvents the process's logback strategy which is what currently feeds both the console and log file.

Comment: Is constructing the objects for the JSON an option for you? @broken_records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was complicating this whole situation by thinking it was an issue with objectMapper.  Instead, my custom OncePerRequestFilter is logging my custom javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper's requestBody which is a byte[] converted to a String so all I needed was to replace the explicit return carriages and line feeds for UTF-8 encoding:

```
stringToWrite.replaceAll("\\r", "").replaceAll("\\n", "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out you *can* set this, but it isn't obvious.
There is probably a better way, but I found this works:

```
    DefaultPrettyPrinter p = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
    DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter i = new DefaultIndenter("  ", "\n");
    p.indentArraysWith(i);
    p.indentObjectsWith(i);

    mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(p);
    String jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myObject);
```